# How to create a transparent image with GraphicsMagick CLI?

Tags: graphicsmagick

I'm coming up empty handed while trying to find out how to modify the opacity of an image using the GraphicsMagick CLI. I'm simply trying to input a standard image and convert it to the corresponding image with a reduced opacity. I'm running GraphicsMagick 1.3.14. Using ImageMagick, I can issue the command:

```
convert input.png -alpha set -channel a -evaluate set 50% +channel output.png
```

However, the `-alpha` option (among others) is unrecognized as a valid GM convert option ([convert option reference here](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/convert.html#conv-opti)). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question was [cross-posted on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/444585/how-to-create-a-transparent-image-with-graphicsmagick-cli), as I later thought SuperUser might be the more appropriate outlet. To quote [Bob Friesenhahn](https://superuser.com/users/144078/bob-friesenhahn):

> The equivalent in GraphicsMagick is
>
> `gm convert input.png -operator Opacity Multiply 0.5 output.png`
>
> or
>
> `gm convert input.png -operator Opacity Assign 50% output.png`
>
> depending on what you really want to do (modulate or assign).
>
> You should add `-matte` prior to `-operator` if you don't know if the image already has an active opacity channel.
>
> Bob